# Foolproof jailbreak detection?

Tags: ios, detection, jailbreak

I went through various posts which talks about jailbreak detection mechanisms. Whatever I came across is either something that apple would reject during the vetting process or something that could be bypassed. I also came to know that apple removed the jailbreak API..

So, is there any foolproof mechanism with which i can check whether a device is jailbroken?

Comment: Why do you need to detect if a device is jail broken? Do you really want to know if your app was cracked? There is a big difference. Checking for a jailbroken device is trivial. Worrying about a pirated app is a fool's errand.

Comment: Just to prevent my app from running on a jailbroken device, don't want this detection mechanism to be bypassed.. Also, should be something which apple wouldn't reject..  Any suggestions?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with letting an app run on a jailbroken device. Most jail breakers are not pirates.

Comment: I agree.. but this one app which i'm talking about, deals with very sensitive information. During pen test, i was able to exploit it n was able to leak sensitive info, on a jailbroken device. So I prefer not letting it run on a jailbroken device.

Comment: If you want to secure your data absolutely completely, then don't let it enter any iOS devices (or any mobile devices in general...).  True security is a myth.  Any system can be cracked given enough resources and enough time.  The trick is to make it harder than what the outcome is worth.

Comment: @ocelot Any user with your app has access to your ipa file through iTunes. A quick unzip of the ipa file and the user has access to all of your app's resources. No hacking or jailbreak required.

Comment: @rmaddy, they may not be concerned about the resources bundled with the app.  They may be worried about the user, or company data, that will be stored on the device if he lets the user start *using* the app.  That's a big difference.  I can envision a number of apps that would not want to allow themselves to be run on a jailbroken phone.  It makes the app developer work much harder to secure data, if they can't rely on Apple's sandboxing.  Then, there's enterprise apps.  You may have a corporate policy that says people can use their own device, as long as it's not jailbroken, or rooted.

Comment: @rmaddy You're right.. and in case of a jailbroken device, those files can be modified on the device and the app would run with tampered resources. This is jus one of the exploits i would like to avoid..

Comment: and @Nate 's comments will add on to my requirements..

Comment: Check out encrypted coredata and other cool tools from project iMAS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is no foolproof way.

Comment: What @borrrden said. In order to detect if a device is jailbroken, your app would need to access deep within the build of the device, which is an illegal action according to apple's submission guidelines.

Comment: hmm.. thats what i thought so.. i was hoping that someone would know of some acceptable way to do this :(

Comment: @jsksma2 It's trivial to check for a jailbroken device and the code passes Apple's checks because it is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: I would have to see this "perfectly legitimate" code, because from what I understand, fetching/altering information about the BSD of a device is not allowed.

Answer (score 5):

I can't claim this is foolproof but I know it works, at least in some cases (if not all). I have had this code in one of my App Store apps for 6 months and 4 updates so Apple appears to be OK with this.

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/bin/bash"] ||
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/Applications/Cydia.app"] ||
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/private/var/lib/apt"]) {
    // Device is jailbroken
}
```

Any good hacker could probably find a way to no-op this code. Making this more hacker proof is an exercise left to the reader.

Comment: Note that this isn't really checking for the jailbreak, but the *artifacts* of jailbreaking, that almost all normal jailbreak users would want to have.  If you're worried about this check being foiled, you should obfuscate the strings you use, and maybe avoid using the Objective-C APIs (C APIs are easy to use for simple file system stuff).  C APIs are a little harder for crackers to replace with no-ops.

Comment: I know this is an old post but note that Cydia is no longer the ONLY Jailbreak App store. The other one is called Sileo

Answer (score 1):

Use this app for Detecting Jailbroken Devices.

[AntiPiracyDemo.ipa](http://code.securitytube.net.s3.amazonaws.com/AntiPiracyDemo.ipa)

Two ways to bypass Jailbreak Detection

1. Runtime Modification using GDB
2. Method Swizzling using Cycript

Have a look at this [Blog](http://hackoftheday.securitytube.net/2013/04/bypassing-jailbroken-checks-in-ios.html) Interesting stuff out there for Bypass Jailbreak Checks.